# What is the cause of this Issue in templates 'undefined reference to'

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have an error, and don't know what is cause, the error message which appeared `undefined reference to int sqlite::bindParam<char const*>(char const*, char const*)`

I have the following class

**Class declaration: `sqlite.h`**

```
class sqlite{

private:
sqlite3 *db_Connection;
sqlite3_stmt *sqlPrepare;

public:
    sqlite();
    int open(const char *db_fileName);
    int close();
    int query(const char *sql);
    template <class T>
    int bindParam(const char *parm_name, T parm_value);
    ~sqlite();
};
```

**The method which is the cause of the problem: `sqlite.cpp`**

```
template <class T>
int sqlite::bindParam(const char *parm_name, T parm_value){
    const std::type_info &parameter_name = typeid(parm_name);
    if(parameter_name == typeid(const char*) || parameter_name == typeid(char*)){
        return sqlite3_bind_text(sqlPrepare, sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(sqlPrepare, parm_name) ,parm_value, 0, 0);
    }else if(parameter_name == typeid(int)) {
        return sqlite3_bind_int(sqlPrepare, sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(sqlPrepare, parm_name), parm_value);
    }else if(parameter_name == typeid(double)){
        return sqlite3_bind_double(sqlPrepare, sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(sqlPrepare, parm_name), parm_value);
    }
}
```

**When usage:**

```
int main(){
    sqlite *sql = new sqlite();

    if(sql->open("database.db") == SQLITE_OK){
        cout << "Connected.";
        sql->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE name=:name");
        sql->bindParam<const char*>(":name", "Fruity");
    }

    delete sql;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know what's wrong in my class specifically `bindParam()` method ?

Comment: is the definition in a header file along with the class declaration ? all my senses tell me you've put `bindParam`'s definition in an implementation file

Comment: The *vast* majority (not all, but nearly so) of undefined-reference linker errors regarding templates are because of incorrect location of the template implementation(s). [**Read this for more info**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: @PiotrS.: the class declaration in independent file (`sqlite.h`), also the class  definition in independent file (`sqlite.cpp`). and the two files along with.

Comment: @LionKing so refer to [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: @LionKing why won't you just add overloads for `double`, `int` and `const char*` (`std::string`) instead of using templates with(!) RTTI ?

Comment: @PiotrS.: I want to be simple and easy to use.

Comment: @LionKing giving explicitly template type argument on each function call is easier than letting compiler do that by dispatching the call to proper overload? adding additional if-else branch whenever you want to support a new parameter type is more readable than additional overload?

Comment: @PiotrS.: Can you give me an example for doing that ?

Comment: @LionKing add member functions as follows: `int bindParam(const char *parm_name, const char* parm_value); int bindParam(const char *parm_name, double parm_value); int bindParam(const char *parm_name, int parm_value);` and define each separately, so that one calls `sqlite3_bind_text`, the second one `sqlite3_bind_double` and the last one calls `sqlite3_bind_int`. none is a function template, so they can go to implementation file just fine

Comment: @PiotrS.: Thanks, but that is overload, and I don't want to use it.

Comment: @LionKing any particular reason for that?

Comment: @PiotrS.: Also unfortunately, I'm still don't understand what in the duplicate question link.

Comment: @LionKing move the definition of `bindParam` to a header file, or add an explicit instantiation definition in an implemntation file

Comment: @PiotrS.: `or add an explicit instantiation definition in an implemntation file`, how ?

Comment: @LionKing put this at the end of the implementation file: `template int sqlite::bindParam<const char*>(const char *parm_name, const char* parm_value);
template int sqlite::bindParam<int>(const char *parm_name, int parm_value);
template int sqlite::bindParam<double>(const char *parm_name, double parm_value);`

Comment: @PiotrS.: Thanks, but there is no way except these ways only ?

Comment: @LionKing no, no other options, out of which adding overloads in place of a function template is the best one

Answer (score 0):

Since you're defining the function template in a source file that's not the same source file in which you're trying to *use* that function template, and since you didn't explicitly instantiate the function template in that source file, it cannot possibly be generated at the point where you need it.

In general it's better to define function templates inside the header files; yes, even though this is the opposite of what is advised for normal templates!

- [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Actually, you *can* define templates in sources files but you need to explicitly instantiate the template in this case: implicit instantiation won't work.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Yes but I wanted to keep it simple for this OP for now, and he or she can read the full FAQ for further details! :-)

Comment: @Asteroids The details should go into your answer. Otherwise it shows that you yourself don't really understand the OP's problem or the answer.